# WSL2 Prompt contains extended WSL path?

Tags: docker-desktop

I'm using build 19042.450 of Windows 10 enterprise, build 2.3.5.1 of the edge version of Docker Desktop and WSL2 integration.  The last Docker Desktop update failed to install fully, but I uninstalled/reinstalled, and now the Docker is working fine.

However, I noticed that my WSL prompt used to look like this:

```
mark@DESKTOP:/mnt/c/CODE$
```

But now looks like this:

```
mark@DESKTOP:/tmp/docker-desktop/shadowing-mounts/f55edec80b1e9ede02de2e973bd22e24a6f111e60342288eca607a63a1f0528b/mnt/c/CODE$
```

And I'm curious if this is a new weird failure or a new feature.

Does anyone know why this long path is now my prompt?